# State a function f(n) that is $O(n^3)$ and $\Omega(n)$ but is not in $\Theta(n^d)$ for any $ 1 \leq d\leq 3$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

> State a function f(n) that is $O(n^3)$ and $\Omega(n)$ but is not in $\Theta(n^d)$ for any $ 1 \leq d\leq 3$

So far I don't think it's possible. But I could be wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As $n \rightarrow ?$

Comment: Can you explain why you think it's impossible?

Comment: @saulspatz Honestly, I saw a post on Chegg saying that it was. So far today Chegg has shown to not be a very good source of information as I’ve found a lot of other obviously wrong answers.

Comment: Hint: have you ever ordered some set with $n$ elements through QuickSort, MergeSort or HeapSort?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** think about logarithms.

**Further hint:** (hidden)

> Consider $f(n)=n \log n$.